# The old library zxing is not running in my app

Tags: java, android, camera, barcode, zxing

What's wrong with this code? I am running the following code in `MainActivity` but I get only an empty app:

```
package com.example.testbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import android.util.Log;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        // Do something with the result here
        Log.v("TAG", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
        // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)
        Log.v("TAG", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        builder.setMessage(rawResult.getText());
        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
        alert1.show();

        // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
        mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        // Start camera on resume
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Stop camera on pause
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

}
```

I've added the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
```

The code builds without errors in Android Studio but I only get an empty app... and no camera when the app runs.

Comment: You followed the simple example from dm77 fork but what your not taking into account is that even though you included the manifest permission you are not checking to see if the user has granted them nor asking for those permissions in the event they have not granted them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ok. How do I "check" that? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow Android's documentation for checking and requesting permissions.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

I have modified your code and this should be a working sample.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        // Do something with the result here
        Log.v("TAG", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
        // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)
        Log.v("TAG", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        builder.setMessage(rawResult.getText());
        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
        alert1.show();

        // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
        mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        // Start camera on resume

        if (hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            startCamera();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Stop camera on pause
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    private void startCamera() {
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    private Boolean hasPermission(String permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // you need to request the permission
            Log.d("TAG", "User hasn't granted permission.");

            // No explanation needed for camera. request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{permission},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
        else {
            Log.d("TAG",  "User already granted permission.");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA:
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    startCamera();
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Permission denied by user...");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working. I had to fieger out from where I can import the "AppCompatActivity", "ContextCompat", "ActivityCompat" and "PackageManager" classes, but it's ok... Now I can use that code in my project. Thanks again!

Comment: Dont forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem. this will help the next person coming along.

Comment: Sory about that. It's "checked" now as solved. Thanks again!